# Pandas: How to create a counter for each duplicated row in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I created a dataframe that contains only duplicated rows using the duplicated() method.
my question is probably quite easy.
i'd like to add a count column to the right and for each row count how many duplicated appearances of it are inside the duplicated df. I thought about creating a groupby of each column but that didn't really work.

something like `df.groupby([*all columns*]).count()`

this is how the df looks like :

[image]

thanks!

**edit :**

question was answered and solved by seabean,
solution could go in either of these methods :

```
newdf = healthdf[healthdf.duplicated(keep = False)].copy()
df_count = newdf.value_counts(dropna = 
False).reset_index(name='count')
df_out = newdf.merge(df_count, how='left')
df_out.drop_duplicates(keep = "first").sort_values("count", ascending 
= False)
```

or

```
col = newdf.columns.to_list()
newdf.groupby(col,dropna=False).size().sort_values(ascending = False)
```

here is the output :

[image]

Comment: you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts 
basicly just use the value_counts() function with the dataframe it will return what you want

Comment: Just read your edit on your final codes used and result. I think I get the reason why you got discrepancy of the 2 counts from postgres and from Pandas. It's because of your code to filter duplicated entries: `newdf = healthdf[healthdf.duplicated()].copy()` You can refer to the [official doc of `.duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) This function sets the first row of every set of duplicated entry False and the others True. Thus, your resulting `newdf` has the first row of each duplicated set removed.  So, got -1 for each.

Comment: To get the correct count, you can use the `keep=False` parameter for `.duplicated()`: `newdf = healthdf[healthdf.duplicated(keep=False)].copy()`

Comment: Got same counts now ?

Comment: yeah, edited original post

Comment: Great we solved it finally, though with certain efforts!   :-)

Comment: Hi @Ori Hait  Seen you got enough reputation to upvote now.  Would you consider to upvote my answer if you find my previous assistance helpful ?  You can upvote my answer by clicking the up arrow ▲ (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments)).    Thanks!

Comment: sure :) thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) + [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), dropna=False)[df.columns[0]].transform('size')
```

As your data contains `NaN`, we have to use parameter `dropna=False` in [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in order to get a complete list of `count` including rows with `NaN` values.  Otherwise, rows with `NaN` values will be skipped and excluded from `count`.

**Demo**

**Data Input**

```
print(df)

  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4
0  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN       # group #1 of 3
1  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN       # group #1 of 3
2  ABC   678  PQR  def       # group #2 of 1
3  MNO   890  EFG  abc       # group #3 of 4 
4  MNO   890  EFG  abc       # group #3 of 4 
5  CDE   234  567  xyz       # group #4 of 2 
6  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN       # group #1 of 3
7  CDE   234  567  xyz       # group #4 of 2 
8  MNO   890  EFG  abc       # group #3 of 4 
9  MNO   890  EFG  abc       # group #3 of 4
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4  count
0  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3           
1  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
2  ABC   678  PQR  def      1
3  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
4  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
5  CDE   234  567  xyz      2
6  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
7  CDE   234  567  xyz      2
8  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
9  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
```

### Edit

If you get memory problem by using the [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) solution, we can go for using the [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) solution by getting the `count` by [`.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html), followed by merging with the original dataframe by [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), as follows:

```
df_count = df.value_counts(dropna=False).reset_index(name='count')  

df_out = df.merge(df_count, how='left')    # left join to keep the original row sequence order of df
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_count)

  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4  count
0  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
1  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
2  CDE   234  567  xyz      2
3  ABC   678  PQR  def      1


print(df_out)

  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4  count
0  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
1  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
2  ABC   678  PQR  def      1
3  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
4  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
5  CDE   234  567  xyz      2
6  ABC   123  XYZ  NaN      3
7  CDE   234  567  xyz      2
8  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
9  MNO   890  EFG  abc      4
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237892/discussion-on-answer-by-seabean-pandas-how-to-create-a-counter-for-each-duplica).